# Using header, body, and property in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

When do I use the following syntax in Apache Camel? I have used in a sample, but don't understand the exact use of it.

```
exchange.setProperty("xx","xx");
exchange.getIn().setHeader("YY","YY");
exchange.getIn().setBody("ZZ")
```

Answer (score 7):

Properties are something that related to the message itself and can be passed between routes.
Headers are often converted to/from protocol headers or affect external communication. The rule is mostly:

- Metadata related to message that is used only inside routes - properties
- Metadata related to some protocol (like HTTP/JMS headers etc) which is outside for routes - headers

Comment: i have a use case in the project where in i will be having List of A_ids where in each A_id contains list of id of type B_ids in turn each B_id  contains list of ids of C.So in each processor i will fetching the Ids by calling a service.I have used a  camel split to iterate A out body data and soo on..what is the ideal way to code in this scenario.please help me here...

Comment: Generally, it depends on the final result you want to have. Will it be just processing in processors? Do you need to aggregate all or partial results somehow?